# CSS link styling troubles

Tags: css, xhtml, hyperlink

I've been making websites for years and theres on thing that really bugs me and confuses me.

I set a link style in the css file for a content div in my website and this successfully styles the links.

However if i create a span or div inside this div with a new link style i end up having to add in `!important` to various attributes which i can only tell by trial and error.

Is there any way around this or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My intuition is that you're having problems with your selector [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity).

Ensure that your new link selectors have a higher specificity than the ones in the enclosing element. Normally this would mean using a selector like `div.outerdiv div.innerdiv a.class` rather than just `a.class` etc.

For example:

```
<div class="outer">
   <a class="outerlink" href="#">Outer Link</a>
   <div class="inner">
      <a class="innerlink" href="#">Inner Link</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

If you use these selectors you may have trouble (depending on css ordering etc.):

```
a.outerlink { **css here** }
a.innerlink { **css here** }
```

Even if you use these selectors, it's not guaranteed to work how you want:

```
.outer a.outerlink {}
.inner a.innerlink {}
```

However, these selectors should work best, ensuring your innerlinks override attributes:

```
.outer a.outerlink {}
.outer .inner a.innerlink {}
```

Make sure you specify **all** the attributes you want to override in the .innerlink css.

Once you understand specificity, the [power of the darkside](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/images/specificitywars-05v2.jpg) will be yours.

Comment: Thanks very much :) - that clears it up - I was half doing this and not all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you are referring to, and I solve this problem by adding "a" after the inside span or div css rule.
Let's assume you have a general rule:

```
a
{
    color:white;
}
```

If you want to override this rule in a div, you have to write

```
div a
{
    color:yellow;
}
```

and not just

```
div
{
    color:yellow;
}
```

This is because the link is inside the div, so the first rule is stronger than the third for links.